# SQL window function in R Language

Tags: r

I want to solve the windowing functions written in `postgresSQL` by using `R` language.

As I know,  `R` has `aggregate()` to calculate group wise data. Whether it has any library to support windowing function ?

Comment: Hi. You need an example that demonstrate what you did with window postegre sql function .

Answer (score 1):

Create the partitions first by calling `group_by`. This way, the following `mutate` call will do its job partition wise. And then ungroup to set the table free. I tried it on a phony salaries table and it appears to have worked.

```
hr_muatated <- hr_sub %>%
  group_by(Department) %>% 
  mutate(
  avg_dep_rate = mean(DailyRate),
  medi_dep_rate = median(DailyRate)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

It gave me this:

```
> as.data.table(hr_muatated)
      EmployeeNumber             Department DailyRate avg_dep_rate medi_dep_rate
   1:              1                  Sales      1102     800.2758         770.5
   2:              2 Research & Development       279     806.8512         810.0
   3:              4 Research & Development      1373     806.8512         810.0
   4:              5 Research & Development      1392     806.8512         810.0
   5:              7 Research & Development       591     806.8512         810.0
  ---                                                                           
1466:           2061 Research & Development       884     806.8512         810.0
1467:           2062 Research & Development       613     806.8512         810.0
1468:           2064 Research & Development       155     806.8512         810.0
1469:           2065                  Sales      1023     800.2758         770.5
1470:           2068 Research & Development       628     806.8512         810.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` and `merge` if you are familiar with SQL syntax.
Taking one of the [example from the PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html), we would use

```
empsalary <- data.frame(depname=rep(c("develop", "personnel", "sales"), c(5, 2, 3)),
                        empno=c(11, 7, 9, 8, 10, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4), 
                        salary=c(5200, 4200, 4500, 6000, 5200, 3500, 3900, 4800, 5000, 4800)) 
merge(empsalary, aggregate(salary ~ depname, empsalary, mean), by="depname")
```

to reproduce the first example (compute average salary by `depname`).

```
     depname empno salary.x salary.y
1    develop    11     5200 5020.000
2    develop     7     4200 5020.000
3    develop     9     4500 5020.000
4    develop     8     6000 5020.000
5    develop    10     5200 5020.000
6  personnel     5     3500 3700.000
7  personnel     2     3900 3700.000
8      sales     3     4800 4866.667
9      sales     1     5000 4866.667
10     sales     4     4800 4866.667
```

You may probably want to look at what [plyr](http://plyr.had.co.nz) has to offer for more elaborated construction.

Comment: Correct, the above solution creates a new data.frame. You could also simulate the merge as follows: `m <- with(empsalary, rep(tapply(salary, depname, mean), table(depname)))`, and `cbind` the resulting vector in your original data.frame. E.g., for avg perc. of salary, we could use `empsalary$avg.perc <- empsalary$salary/m*100`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Suppose I want to solve the below query in R language:
SELECT depname, empno, (salary * avg(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY depname))*100,(cost * avg(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY depname))*100 FROM empsalary 
then, Do I need to write a separate merge and create a temp data frame for each windowing function and merge all for final result..?

Comment: Nope. You can use what I proposed (compute mean by group and expand by row, then add as a new column to your data.frame); you would just add a second aggregate step, replacing `salary` with `cost`. (BTW, *don't remove your comments*, otherwise future readers won't be able to follow the conversation.)

Comment: I removed the comment as I have unfortunately posted it without completing. Anyway Thank you for your valuable reply :)